# How to make manual retry thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to do a manual retry. But I feel the code is not thread safe.
Can anyone please provide suggestion on how to make it thread safe

```
while (retryCounter < maxRetries) {
          try {
            //TODO - add delay with config
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            t.run();
            break;
          } catch (Exception e) {
            retryCounter++;
            //TODO - Add audit logs
            if (retryCounter >= maxRetries) {
              LOG.info("Max retries exceeded");
              //TODO - remove exception add audit logs
              throw new RuntimeException("Max retry exceeded");
            }
          }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are aware that `t.run()` synchronously calls the run method of your `t` object and does not actually start an async thread?

Comment: Why you feel it not thread safe? There even no "thread". The code is run in single thread.

Comment: my application will run on servers where it will  ot be single threaded

Comment: Is the type of `t` not `Thread` ?

Comment: no it is a interface method

Comment: Last attempt :-) - what is the type of `t` ?

Comment: t is an interfrace interface Throwable { void run throws Exception}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @ SteffenJacobs, `t.run` does not execute the run logic on a separate thread but rather on the thread that makes the invocation. If you replace `t.run` with `t.start` then the run logic will be executed on a different thread **asynchronously** which means that exceptions in that new thread will never be handled by your `catch` block. For example the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int retryCounter = 0;
    int maxRetries = 3;

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("..." + Thread.currentThread());
            throw new RuntimeException("Thrown by me!!!");
        }});

    while (retryCounter < maxRetries) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("***" + Thread.currentThread());
            t.start();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("retrying attempt " + retryCounter);
            System.out.println(e);
            retryCounter++;
            if (retryCounter >= maxRetries) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Max retry exceeded");
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.println("in finally");
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
***Thread[main,5,main]
in finally
...Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Thrown by me!!!
...
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Bottom line** - To detect errors in your threaded tasks, you will need to think of a different approach. 
You could consider using `Future`s (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). In this case your tasks will need to return a status of their execution while the code that launched them waits on `Future.get` , examines the status and reruns the task as needed.

Comment: if the exception is not handled why code prints runtimeexception

Comment: It is not printed by your/mine code, it is printed by the VM's exception handler.

Comment: I am unable to understand why run time exception is thrown

Comment: I amended the sample code to emphasize the source of the exception

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @David Soroko is very close, but I think it need little modification. As your code would run under `multi-threaded` environment, we should take care of **Synchronization**

If multiple thread tries to enter `while` loop, it may happen that 2 invocations of `Retry Thread` would get started, with 2 calls of `t.start()`. Ideally, we should start only single invocation during single iteration of while loop.

Little modification :

Declare `LOCK` object in your class level

```
// Object to ensure thread safety between multiple threads
private final LOCK = new Object();
```

Use `LOCK` object with `synchronized` block in `while` loop

```
synchronized(LOCK) { // This will ensure single thread entry at a time
    while (retryCounter < maxRetries) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("***" + Thread.currentThread());
            t.start();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("retrying attempt " + retryCounter);
            System.out.println(e);
            retryCounter++;
            if (retryCounter >= maxRetries) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Max retry exceeded");
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.println("in finally");
        }
    }
}
```

The variables `retryCounter` and `maxRetries` are read by multiple threads. This means they are shared resources between threads. We need to ensure thread safety there as well. There is concept of `Atomicity` and `Volatility`.

**Atomicity** : When any thread `T1` is doing operation on Variable `A`, at the same time, if other thread `T2` tries to do operation on `A`, either operation of `T1` should get completed fully or operation of `T1` should be aborted fully, before starting operation of `T2`.

**Volatility** : When multiple threads are accessing single variable `A`, all threads should read the actual value from memory. In multithreaded environment, depending on processor, threads do optimisation while reading variable resources like `A`. Optimised value of `A` may not match actual value of `A` in memory. This may lead to **Race condition** or misbehaviour of your business logic. In your case, the `Retry` operation may run more than `Max Retry` count in case of misbehaviour.

Make both shared resources to comply **Volatile** and **Atomic** properties

```
final AtomicInteger retryCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
final AtomicInteger maxRetries = new AtomicInteger(3);
```